# bash: adb: command not found (chromebook)

Tags: linux, adb, chromebook

I am on a chromebook with adb enabled but when I use "abd install pckg.apk" it doesn't work, I've tried disabling and re-enabling it and it still doesnt work. I've also used the command while SuperUser/root and it still gives me the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? "not found"? Did you install adb? (How?) What is your `$PATH` variable? What does `ls -l /usr/bin/adb` say? If that does not come back empty, what happens when you run `/usr/bin/adb install pckg.apk`? Please check [ask]...

Answer (score -1):

You need to install adb by typing the below command in the Linux console.

**sudo apt install adb**